# Is it bad to "monitor" a database table by constantly querying for PRIMARY_ID > lastProcessedId

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, elasticsearch

I'm indexing a MySQL table in ElasticSearch (full-text search). Instead of sending each new row at the time of its creation, we do a SQL query each N seconds (~30 seconds) for new records in that table. We do that by storing the last processed record ID (auto_increment) and issuing a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable where id > lastProcessedId
```

My question: is this a good way to handle this? Are there any critical drawbacks? Are there any better alternatives?

We were also planning to use the same approach to handle users 'likes' (facebook style). Every N seconds we do a SQL query to get the latest 'likes' then process them and update each users' timeline.

We are trying to do it this way to avoid to mess with an old code base. But I'm not very comfortable with issuing this type of query each second, for example.

Any thoughts or problems with this solution?

Comment: Depending on how your application handled transactions, your SELECT might miss some records when, e.g., two transactions concurrently INSERT multiple records.  Subsequent SELECTs would then wrongly assume they've seen every lower ID.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds expensive,  I would consider other approaches.

1. Modify old code to index stuff on insert!  I know it can be scary, but is it that bad? :)
2. Create an insert trigger that would somehow kick off an re-index process,  i think you could have lots of options for how to build this.

Check out,  http://www.roseindia.net/sql/trigger/mysql-trigger-after-insert.shtml

Comment: The indexing occurs outside MySQL, don't know if a insert trigger would help me in that case.

Comment: Yes, you need http to index in elastic search.  I've never done it, but you could potentially add new native function to mysql.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-native-function.html

Answer (score 0):

It's a little expensive, but frankly, if it's only every 30 seconds, I'd do it that way till it started to get painful.

There are other places you can put the data to pickup later and process, instead of staging via the database. You could use something as simple as appending a serialised copy to a file, writing a new one every 30-60 seconds, and then have a script process the previous unprocessed file(s). Similarly, you can put them into some other sort of queue, and then run that as often as you want.